# mongoDb driver for windows phone

Tags: mongodb, windows-phone-8, mongodb-.net-driver

Is it possible to access a MongoDB Database Server from a Windows Phone 8 App?

Is it possible to do so using Native App, using c# as the programming language?

Please excuse me if this is a stupid question. I am new to MongoDB.

I wish to perform CRUD operations from the Phone.

The official C# Driver targets .Net Framework v3.5
I failed to install it on the Windows phone project using nugget.

error-

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'mongocsharpdriver 1.8.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package mongocsharpdriver
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: There is a MongoDB C# driver, but I'm afraid it is not compatible with Windows Phone. [Here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/) can find more information. Maybe other "not official" driver exists.

Comment: I will try to compile it from source. Fingers Crossed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drivers won't work for many reasons.

The biggest is that the current .NET drivers/source require synchronous communication support. The Windows Phone .NET libraries only support asynchronous communication. So, anything that's synchronous would need to be changed.

There's a line of code for example in the current code:

```
tcpClient.Connect(ipEndPoint);
```

Minimally, this would need to be changed to be in an `async` method using the `await` keyword:

```
await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ipEndPoint);
```

However, it's not as simple as that, as the ConnectAsync doesn't support use of the `async` keyword as it doesn't use `Task`s. Instead, it has a different connection syntax where the method expects an object, that has an event which is called when the connection has established. And, that's just one example.

I'd suggest that instead of directly connecting to a MongoDB, you instead use a web server or service to proxy the database communication. There, you could use a REST API for example and use the C# drivers from an ASP.NET hosted application (for example, using the ASP.NET Web APIs).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you using [Sleepy Mongoose](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/)
which is a full `HTTP` interface for `MongoDB`. And accordingly, you don't need any drivers, you just need to perform some `HTTP` requests to apply `CRUD` operations from your mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

This **[npm module - express-restify-mongoose](https://npmjs.org/package/express-restify-mongoose)** is a good option for people using a **node.js** server. This library provides **mongoose database models with a REST interface**.